# International month in django urls

Tags: python, django, localization, django-urls

I have this permalink def:

```
@models.permalink
def get_absolute_url(self):
        creation_date = timezone.localtime(self.start_publication)
        return ('entry_detail', (), {
            'year': creation_date.strftime('%Y'),
            'month': creation_date.strftime('%b').lower(),
            'day': creation_date.strftime('%d'),
            'slug': self.slug})
```

The url looks like this:

/news/2012/oct/20/slug-title

The oct is in english, not my local specified language. How can I get "okt" instead of "oct"?

Here is my settings:

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'nb'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
```